# update returns 0 when referring field names using colons ":" in attached sqlite databases

Tags: java, sqlite

Two SQLITE databases are attached. (alias: main, sourceDb)
Trying to update matching records  from one of sourceDb table to main database table.

Tried below query in java (android studio) using sqliteDB.update function. It returns 0 always. 
Also manually in "DB Browser for SQLITE" application but returs 0

```
`UPDATE main.table1 
SET Field1 = :Field1, 
Field2 = :Field2 
WHERE 
CAST(keyField1 as VARCHAR) || CAST(keyField2 as VARCHAR) = 
CAST(:keyField1 as VARCHAR) || CAST(:keyField2 as VARCHAR)`
```

Is there a problem when using ":" to refer the sourceDB field?
I can see matching records are available.

Comment: You cannot use `update()` for arbitrary SQL, use `execSQL()` for that. You can only bind values, not identifiers such as column names. Please post the code that tries to run this SQL.

Comment: Thnx for the reply. Ok I'll make this simple as below. Below codes I executed in DB Browse for SQLITE.

This line returns rows.
select * from sourceDB.table1 where int_key = 1245

This line also returns rows.
select * from main.table1 where int_key = 1245

which means both table has rows that maches the int_key = 1245.

But below line does not return any rows.

select * from main.table1 where int_key = :int_key

Comment: How are you binding the value for your `int_key` variable?

Comment: Actually in this select statement int_key is a field name. Not a variable